# Can I be held to what a rental lease says if the landlord misinforms me about what it says?

Tags: real-estate-leasing

However, he claims that according to the contract I have to inform them 2 full months in advance (by a certain date of the month, so effectively 3 months now) in order to leave or be responsible for the remainder?

I'm guessing that legally I am bound by the paper. However, now i've become really curious. To what extent is a landlord allowed to lie about the written agreement?

can they say that I'm signing a month-to-month renewal contract when in reality they are signing me into a contract for a year?

Comment: What does the contract say?  [Month to month](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/month-to-month-tenancy.asp) generally means what you expect... but it all depends on the agreement you signed.  They can basically say what they want about the agreement. It's up to you to read and understand it. *Caveat emptor!*

Comment: It feels like there's some text missing from this question. It starts with "However" but there's nothing prior to that to be contrasted to or contradicted.

Answer (score 5):

If there wasn't a written contract you might have an argument that you had an oral agreement, which can be binding (just hard to enforce), but I'm afraid that once you signed that contract, anything they said to you is pretty much irrelevant. That's why you should read very closely what you sign or have an attorney look at it for you.

In any event, the fact that you have a month-month lease doesn't preclude the notice requirement. It just means that your lease continues to renew itself each month if neither party affirmatively terminates it.

I don't get where you think that they are signing you into a contract for a year, when they are only requiring 2 months of notice.

Comment: it's 3 months notice effectively, which is basically a quarter of the year. 95% of the contract was a duplicate of the original, so I didn't wish to read the entire thing again line by line like I did the first time, but I guess I should have. I just think that 3 months notice on a month to month lease seems ridiculous

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet  Never ...  EVER  ...  sign something that you have not read in full, especially when you know beforehand that there's money involved.

Comment: Your best bet is that they didn't specify explicitly what the penalties are for not giving enough notice. BTW: I still don't see how 2 months notice=3 months notice=1/4 year = 1 year.

Comment: @JohnFx, the lease probably has a fine-print somewhere explaining what constitutes a 2-month notice, and says something like the 1st day of the month that is two-month prior to the month you are moving out in. So if you're moving out close to the last day of May, you need to notify them prior to March 1, which effectively becomes 3 month. This is becoming increasingly popular with shady landlords.